# Subgroup of order $n$ of $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$

Tags: matrices, group-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields

I am looking for a subgroup of order $n$ of $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ where $q=p^a$ with $p$ prime and $a\ge 1$.

I know that $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_2)$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{A}_3$ but it does not fit with the statement...

Thanks in advance !

Comment: A subgroup of what?

Comment: Why is there a downvote ?

Answer (score 2):

The subgroup generated by the cyclic permutation matrix $$\left(\begin{matrix}0 & 0 & 0& \cdots & 0& 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0& 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0& 0\\ 0 & 1& 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0& 0\\ 0 & 0 &1& \cdots & 0 & 0& 0\\ \vdots &\vdots &\vdots &   &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots \\ 0& 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 0& 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0& \cdots &  0&1 & 0\\ \end{matrix}\right)$$

has the same order as the size of the matrix. This does not depend on the field where the coefficients live.

Comment: Would the downvoter explain his/her point of view?

Comment: Thank you for finding one example ! But I was looking for one with $\mathbb{F}_q$

Comment: @Maman This example **is** for $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Comment: @Maman What makes you think this wouldn't work for $\Bbb F_q$?

Comment: The group you gave is isomorphic to a subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ but which one ?

Comment: It is not only isomorphic, it *is* a subgroup. And this holds in any field (with a multiplicative unit that you call $1$).

Comment: I know but can we be more precise on the subgroup ? For instance, is it $SL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ ?

Comment: I don't know how to be more precise than an explicit description of the elements. And no it is not $ SL_n $, $ SL_n $ is huge compared to $ n $.

Comment: @Maman The group is called "cyclic group $C_n$".